# CSS Display Empty DIV ONLY if there is content

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a div (essentially will become a tooltip) that will display when hovered; however, I need it to display ONLY if there is content in the div

```css
[data-tip] {
    position:relative;
}
[data-tip]:after{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    content:attr(data-tip);
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
[data-tip]:hover:after+[data-tip].active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="tooltip active" data-tip="This should display tooltip"></div>
<div className="tooltip" data-tip="">This should not display</div>
```

Obviously the CSS is not complete with positioning, etc. but Ineed the most important part to work and thats displaying only when there is content in the `data-tip`

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: @Morpheus Need it to display if an attribute is empty, not the entire div.

Comment: TIL that you can do attribute selectors. Cool!

Comment: This div wraps an input and a label. If there is a validation error on the input field I set the "data-tip" in the div to display a popup tooltip; however, I need the tooltip to only popup if the contents if 1) data-tip is not "" AND 2) I hover over the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more solution using css

```css
[data-tip] {
    position:relative;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
}
[data-tip]:after{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    content:attr(data-tip);
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
[data-tip]:not([data-tip=""]):hover:after{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="tooltip" data-tip="">This should not display</div>
<div className="tooltip" data-tip="This should display tooltip">div1</div>
<div className="tooltip" data-tip="">This should not display as well</div>
<div className="tooltip" data-tip="This should display tooltip">this should display again</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check empty attributes.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-tip]").forEach(p => {
  p.getAttribute("data-tip") == '' ? p.style.display = 'none' : '';
});
```

```css
[data-tip] {
    position:relative;
}
[data-tip]:after{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    content:attr(data-tip);
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
[data-tip]:hover:after+[data-tip].active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="tooltip active" data-tip="This should display tooltip"></div>
<div className="tooltip" data-tip="">This should not display</div>
```

This will also work when it contains spaces with `trim()` function.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-tip]").forEach(p => {
  p.getAttribute("data-tip").trim() == '' ? p.style.display = 'none' : '';
});
```

```css
[data-tip] {
    position:relative;
}
[data-tip]:after{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    content:attr(data-tip);
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
[data-tip]:hover:after+[data-tip].active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="tooltip active" data-tip="This should display tooltip"></div>
<div className="tooltip" data-tip="       ">This should not display</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following selector?

```
[data-tip]:not([data-tip=''] {

}
```